# Not getting name in Sign in with Apple

Tags: flutter, apple-sign-in

I am trying to integrate Apple sign in in flutter, following guide on [sign_in_with_apple_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple) and everything seems to go well, I get the screen like this one:

[image]

The process is ok up until i get the id token to retrieve the info from the backend, but now the info received only includes email, see my result (after decoding id token):

```
{
  "iss": "https://appleid.apple.com",
  "aud": "com.app.test",
  "exp": 1694727453,
  "iat": 1694641053,
  "sub": "xxx",
  "at_hash": "xxx",
  "email": "xxx@privaterelay.appleid.com",
  "email_verified": "true",
  "is_private_email": "true",
  "auth_time": 1694641048,
  "nonce_supported": true
}
```

My googling has however not proven fruitful and I have struggled with this for quite sometime, did I miss something here, or how do I get the names plus the email of the user, thanks.

Comment: [https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121496](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121496)
Old problem, the name is only provided the first time your application requests access, you must save it in the local bank until you register.

Comment: So if I goto "Stop using Apple ID" process and retry, I should be able to get the name, right?

Comment: Yes, return the name again. But for the user use case, you must save the name in a database, there is no other way out unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, I got it, basically the name is in the authorization result, i was actually trying to retrieve the name using the identity token in the backend, so now i just transfer the name to the backend alongside the id token