# Firebase authentication with Apple does not provide user email

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Flutter app with a authentication flow using Firebase Authentication and I want to create an entry in Cloud Firestore with the `email` retrieved from the `user` field of the `UserCredential` object returned by the [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) library on sign-in.

This works perfectly for Google and Email+passowrd authentication providers, however for Apple that `email` is . I was expecting to get a private email of the type "@privaterelay.appleid.com" but I am not. **How can I get the email of Apple users on sign-up?**

In addition, on Firebase console in the Authentication view almost all the user are being registered with an empty "identifier" (where the email should be), however some are also registered with their "@privaterelay.appleid.com" emails. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: [https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121496](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121496) Old problem, the name and email are only provided the first time your application requests access, you must save it in the local database until you register. If you still want access to the email, decode the token, inside it will be the email. [See this question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77100781/not-getting-name-in-sign-in-with-apple?noredirect=1#comment135943299_77100781)

Comment: That thread is about the package `singin_with_apple` and not `firebase_auth` as indicated in the question. In addition, the problem in my case it that event the first time the app request access I am NOT receiving the email information in the returned `UserCredential`

Comment: Read the answer on the Apple forum.

Comment: I have read the answer in Apple forum, and it indicates (for Swift) that the email information is available only on sign-up (first sign-in), however as stated in the question this is not returned by the Flutter library and I get `null` for the email property. The "token" object returned in `UserCredential.credential` is also `null`.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you're observing with Firebase Authentication and Apple sign-in is expected, and it's due to how Apple handles user privacy and data protection.

**Email Privacy Protection:**

Apple's Sign In with Apple feature prioritizes user privacy by providing users with the option to hide their email addresses when signing in to third-party apps. When users choose to hide their email addresses, Apple generates a unique and random email address (e.g., "@privaterelay.appleid.com") that forwards emails to the user's real email address. This feature is known as "Email Privacy Protection."

When a user signs in with Apple and chooses to hide their email address, Firebase Authentication will indeed return a random email address like "@privaterelay.appleid.com" in the UserCredential object, instead of the user's actual email address.

**Firebase Authentication Identifier:**

The "identifier" field you see in Firebase Authentication's user list is where Firebase stores the user's email or other identifier. However, when a user signs in with Apple and hides their email address, Firebase will indeed store the "@privaterelay.appleid.com" address as the identifier, as that's the information provided by Apple.

The reason some users are registered with empty identifiers in Firebase Authentication could be due to various reasons, including issues with token exchange between your app and Firebase during the authentication process or errors during user creation.

To address these challenges and to ensure you have the user's actual email address (if available), you can follow these steps:

**Check the Apple identityToken:**

When a user signs in with Apple, the UserCredential object contains an identityToken field. **You can decode this token to extract the user's real email address if it's available.** Note that the email address will only be included if the user did not choose to hide it during the sign-in process. You can use a library like jwt_decode to decode the token and extract the email.

**Request Email Scopes:**

When integrating Sign In with Apple in your app, ensure that you request the necessary email-related scopes when initiating the sign-in process. This might increase the chances of obtaining the user's actual email address.

**Handle Missing Emails Gracefully:**

Be prepared for cases where the user's email is not available (e.g., they chose to hide it). In such cases, you can inform the user that their email is not accessible due to privacy settings.

Remember to keep your app's user experience respectful of privacy choices made by users, and always handle sensitive user data with care in accordance with relevant privacy laws and regulations.

Comment: The first problem I have is in most cases Firebase is NOT storing the "@privaterelay.appleid.com" address as the identifier and is just left empty (see the screenshot in the question).  The "token" object returned in `UserCredential.credential` is `null`, and the "accessToken" object throws and exception when trying to decode it with *jwt_decode* package. Adding "email" and "name" scopes to the `AppleAuthProvider` did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip this whole story if you not interested and go to **TLDR** section.

So just today I faced this issue and upon checking logs and firebase users list i was quickly able to see that for some users i have email and for some users i don't have email address when they are signed up using firebase apple auth provider, but one thing that i could not understand in the beginning was why apple is doing this? if user has opted to hide his email it's fine but then apple should have provided me with `@privaterelay.appleid.com` but in my case email was not there at all which made me think either something is wrong with my implementation or Apple authentication so upon checking my my code for apple sign in i was quickly able to see the issue and the issue was i did not provided any `scope` to the auth provider which was causing this issue but that's not all it took me to fix this issue.

Here is how i defined the scope

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

final appleProvider = AppleAuthProvider();
appleProvider.addScope('email');
appleProvider.addScope('name');
UserCredential userCredential =
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(appleProvider);
```

Although now i have defined the `scope` but still while attempting to sign in with Apple i was getting the same issue.

Now you all be thinking what's the fix for this now??
It might seem challenging, but fixing this issue is actually quite straightforward. When a user signs in using their Apple ID, Apple saves their preferences regarding how they want to share their account information with the app. So, the next time the user signs in using the same app, Apple already knows how to handle it without requiring them to make those decisions again.

Now, the question arises: how can users delete those preferences? As this is crucial for Apple to respond appropriately to new sign-in requests with different scopes than before. It's pretty easy you can follow [this](https://basalt-smartphone-e79.notion.site/iPhone-Apple-Sign-In-issue-patch-17a8259947474d9a8ba85e1de57f7ba7) guide I made or if you are smart enough just open on the following:

```
Settings > Apple ID > Sign-In & Security > Sign-In with Apple
```

Once you reach here you will see multiple apps showing up and so now you can click on your app and you will see a button wit red text which says `Stop using Apple ID` you can go ahead and click on it and confirm stop using, doing this will remove the user preference on how Apple should react to future Sign-In requests.

**Too long did not read (TLDR)?**

To fix this issue you should do the following:

- Ensure you have proper scope defined as mentioned above.
- Secondly ensure you have removed any preference saved in to your Apple ID  regarding how data will be shared with your app as it's crucial for this new scope to work.
- Follow [this](https://basalt-smartphone-e79.notion.site/iPhone-Apple-Sign-In-issue-patch-17a8259947474d9a8ba85e1de57f7ba7) link to remove Sign-In preferences for your app.

Comment: any affiliation with the linked site? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: @starball it's a notion page managed by me.

Comment: you need to disclose affiliation explicitly in the post.

Comment: @starball I'm sorry I'm not sure what to do do you have an example?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145588/997587

Comment: The guide for deleting the sign-in preferences is applicable only to users that have already signed-in with Apple Id? If defining the scope works for new user, that would be the solution to this problem. Otherwise for an app with 50k+ user it is not feasible to ask them follow that guide...

Comment: @pcba-dev I agree!!

Answer (score -2):

That is the way apple sign in works. Users can choose to not share their e-mail.

Comment: Your answer is not correct, even in cases where the user chooses not to provide their email, a private email is exposed the first time you log in. Subsequent attempts are not provided with the email.